# How to use Glase on a rooted Android device?

Tags: root-access, nfc, hidden, magisk, root-cloak

How can I use the Tap and Pay payment app *Glase* (formerly *SEQR*) on a device which has been rooted using Magisk?

Answer (score 0):

- Step 0. Clean/uninstall everything Glase/SEQR, in other words - start over.
- Step 1. Install Glase from Play Store but don't open it!
- Step 2. Open Magisk Manager, hit "Tap to start SafetyNet check". Allow download of non-OSS if asked for. If Magisk notifies you that it has been repackaged and the check cannot be performed, you'll have to use a third-party app to check for SafetyNet Status.
- Step 3. Ensure both basicIntegrity and ctsProfile are true. If not, ensure Magisk Hide is enabled by toggling its setting inside Magisk Manager settings, under Magisk. On Huawei devices on stock ROM you have to flash a specific "patch" zip file via TWRP recovery. If even after enabling Magisk Hide ctsProfile and/or basicIntegrity are false, please reboot your device, and - if it still doesn't work - reinstall stock firmware/ROM and start over. Please note that on some custom ROMs you'll have to use the "Props" Magisk Module to enable Magisk Hide.
- Step 4. Go into Magisk Hide from the Magisk Manager menu and select/mark your Glase or SEQR app as enabled. You should see an orange ticked (✓) tick box next to it.
- Step 5. Now go into Magisk Manager settings and select the "Hide Magisk Manager" entry from "General" menu. If you don't see it, and instead have "Restore Magisk Manager", it means you have done this already and you can go to the next step.
- Step 6. Now open your Glase/SEQR app and follow the on-screen instructions to set it up.
  Note: the "Tap and Pay Activation" procedure is sometimes buggy, regardless if you're rooted or not. Please allow up to 2 minutes for Glase to send you an "Activated" notification. If you don't get one, please delete app data of Glase, re-sign in with your account and attempt "Tap and Pay Activation" again